# Adding Google play service map and location dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

How to include both maps and location google play dependencies in your  android project?This is what I am doing-

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
    compile('eu.inmite.android.lib:android-validation-komensky:0.9.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.7'
    compile project(':libstreaming')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
//    compile('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.2') {
//        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
//    }

}
```

**And this is what I am getting-** 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
>     You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
>     However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed this  compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.1'
to compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'.

This was fixed in the updated version of map utils.It worked.

Answer (score 3):

`play-services-location` actually contains `play-services-maps` as a dependency, so you can remove the `maps` line entirely.

You can use `./gradlew dependencies` to check where exactly certain dependencies are coming from - that may help you narrow down exactly which libraries are also including portions of Google Play services - make sure you also don't have it as a jar file in your `libs` directory.

Comment: ok may be you are right but I am still getting the same error.This time because of the map utils.

Comment: compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }

Comment: @user949884 - of course, it is `play-services-maps` that contains [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng), a somewhat important part of location (and the reason behind the underlying dependency).

Comment: I don't need it for my app.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove full package of play services dependency and add only required dependencies eg. compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1' if you are using location service and compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1' if you are using map service.

Answer (score -2):

remove

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
```

and add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

Comment: Also you may not need  " compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.1'" either

Comment: I already tried that,reached 65k limit.Therefore looking for alternatives.

Comment: Selectively compiling the API you need is a better way to do it .